# How can I make a specific series of URLS have "410" Gone status?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Server was hacked and my *.htaccess* file was changed to wildcard redirect (spam).

I am seeing a lot of requests like those below even after I've cleaned up my server:

```
example.com/cobwebbing-gurkha1486mskh27556/64b75843rl69s2/
example.com/countercheck-gurkha1486mskh22793/n4a670a2h43m/
example.com/countercheck-gurkha1486mskh19573/36c9on2137rs/
```

How can I change those URL to `410 Gone`?  I'd like to redirect them to a page I've made (fail.php) that issues a 410 header.

Here is the current hacked htaccess.   I tried to make the end part of the file (`?gurkha`) to go to `fail.php` but it doesn't seem to work. It keeps going to a the WordPress 404 page.   The WordPress 404 eats up system memory and I'd like a more elegant and efficient way to handle these URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^\/(.*)-(gurkha)([0-9]+)mskh([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?gurkha$3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
</IfModule>
```

I'd really like to get these URLS off google.  How can I change my *.htaccess* so they are `410 Gone`?

Comment: You need a space before the `[L]` in your final rerwrite rule and you need to move it up before the `RewriteCond`s.  MrWhite's answer that shows how to return the status directly at the URLs would be better though.   You shouldn't redirect to show a different status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> /cobwebbing-gurkha1486mskh27556/64b75843rl69s2/
> /countercheck-gurkha1486mskh22793/n4a670a2h43m/
> /countercheck-gurkha1486mskh19573/36c9on2137rs/
> ```

To force a URL that contains `-gurkha` followed by a digit fail early with a system generated 404 (bypassing WordPress), then you can use something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule -gurkha\d - [R=404]
```

Note that this must go *before* the WordPress front-controller. ie. *before* the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` directive. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

If, however, you still see a WordPress generated 404 page then it's possible that you have a custom 404 error document that points to a WordPress document (eg. `404.php`). You can reset this to the simple Apache default by including the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

If you want Google to drop these URLs quicker then you can change the `R=404` flag to `G` (`gone`) to serve a 410 Gone instead. (Although this potentially alerts users/bots/hackers to this - but that probably is not a real concern.) Again, reset the `ErrorDocument` (as above) if you still see a WordPress page returned.

You can then use the [Google Search Console URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal) to explicitly remove these URLs from the SERPS.

A 401 Unauthorized response won't necessarily make Google drop the URL. And it will only likely raise further suspicion. (Although, it seems the OP initially referenced "401" in error and actually meant "410".)

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^\/(.*)-(gurkha)([0-9]+)mskh([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?gurkha$3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
</IfModule>
```

You should remove that last `RewriteRule`. As it stands, it will not do anything, but also has several "errors":

1. In per-directory `.htaccess` files, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against never starts with a slash. So, this `RewriteRule` would never match anything in this context.
2. By placing this directive *after* the front-controller, it will only be seen for URL requests that map to physical files or directories. These URLs probably don't map to real files/directories, so again it would never match.
3. By placing directive inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` / `# END WordPress` block then it will likely get overwritten when WordPress updates.

Other, "less serious" points regarding that last `RewriteRule`:

4. There is no space between the *CondPattern* and the *flags* (ie. before the `[L]`). This would potentially result in an invalid rewrite. And potentially cause problems if you later added more directives (because there is no `L` flag).
5. No need to backslash escape slashes (eg. `\/`) in standard Apache regex. (Spaces are used as delimiters and slashes otherwise carry no special meaning.)
6. Many unnecessary captured groups (parenthesised subpatterns) that are not used.

Comment: I tried it, it still goes to 404 wordpress, even at the very very top, but i put this in, and it works.. 

ErrorDocument 401 /fail.php
RewriteRule -gurkha\d - [R=401]

and then in fail.php I have nothing exept a Header 401 and it seems to fire off the default 401 for apache and not wordpress.  Is what i have ok?  if i goto any other URL it goes to the 404 page in wordpress so it seems to only work for that regex? or maybe its any 401 page since i defined it custom

Comment: and console log now says this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (GONE)"

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? `RewriteRule -gurkha\d - [R=404]` should not trigger the WordPress 404, unless you perhaps have an `ErrorDocument` defined somewhere that sends these requests through WordPress?! But you shouldn't be sending a 401 if you want these URLs to be dropped from the SERPs - I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: "in fail.php I have nothing exept a Header 401" - you wouldn't even need the "Header 401" if you've defined an `ErrorDocument` - Apache will already send the appropriate response header.

Comment: "if i goto any other URL it goes to the 404 page in wordpress so it seems to only work for that regex?" - Yes, that is what you want; isn't?

Comment: "and console log now says this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (GONE)" - So, you've changed this to a 410?

Comment: your answer got me to where I need.  I made a small tweak to get the 410 error redirect page to show up and bypass wordpress by doing the ErrorDocument 410 /410.php but other than that we are good to go.  Thanks for your help

Comment: yes i meant 410 not 401 and making the page, setting the error doc, and using your regex fixed it

Comment: For the htaccess code, if the URL was set to 301, does this successfully change it from a 301 to a 404? I was under the impression that 301s were probably cached in the browser and not from the server. This code can successfully undo a 301 into a 404?

Comment: You're welcome. Just to add, you wouldn't expect to have to set something like `ErrorDocument 410 /410.php`, unless this was already defined _somewhere_ (server config, virtual host, `.htaccess`) and you needed to override this. But to clear this and get the server to issue a default response then you just need `ErrorDocument 410 default`. No need for `410.php` unless you want to customize the response (which you probably don't want to do for this).

Comment: @Michaeld Not sure what you mean? Yes, 301s are typically cached by the browser, but this does not appear to be a caching issue.

Comment: @MrWhite yes but I have a similar problem of my domain being 301 redirected and Google never fixed the issue, causing the 301 redirect to stand despite the homepage and directories returning status 200. It seems Google forever caches 301 redirects. My post here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113458/built-a-site-on-a-domain-that-was-previously-301-redirected-google-wont-crawl (don't mean to hijack this thread but it's probably helpful to the OP regardless)

Comment: @Michaeld That would seem to be a _different_ problem. There's no suggestion that 301 redirects were ever used here.